# How to write files larger than 2 GB?

Tags: file, file-io, rust, filesystems

The following code:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let encoded: Vec<u8> = vec![0; 2500000000];
    let mut buffer = File::create("file.bin").unwrap();
    let written_bytes = buffer.write(&encoded).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(written_bytes, encoded.len());
}
```

errors with:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `2147479552`,
 right: `2500000000`', src/main.rs:8:5
```

So there seems to be a limit of `2^31 - 4096` bytes.

How can I get around this? I'd like to write a larger file. :)

Comment: Also, create a vector of 2.5 GO is not reasonable. Use a smaller buffer. 2^8 to 2^16, is way better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rusts `write` relies on the underlying OS to write the bytes.

For Linux systems the [write syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) will be used.

> According to POSIX.1, if `count` is greater than `SSIZE_MAX`, the result is implementation-defined; see NOTES for the upper limit on Linux.

Notes:

> On Linux, `write()` (and similar system calls) will transfer at most `0x7ffff000` (2,147,479,552) bytes, returning the number of bytes actually transferred.  (This is true on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems.)

So there the magic number is coming from.

To circumvent your problem, use [`write_all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#method.write_all) instead of `write`, which will make sure, that all bytes are written.

As a note: If you run the program under Windows, the will run just fine.

Comment: Thanks. That's even better. No `BufWriter` needed after all. :)

Comment: @TobiasHermann: For performance reasons, a `BufWriter` is still likely to be preferable. Try benchmarking both.

Comment: I don't think, posix specifically matter, just the doc of rust write is enough. "Write a buffer into this object, returning how many bytes were written.", https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.write

Comment: @Stargateur you're right, but the manpage explains why only 2147479552 bytes were written.